# How to validate files users are sending before uploading it to a server? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, browser

Had minimal luck.

In the below code snippet, I tried to first prevent event propagation so it wouldn't upload just yet.

I had the following assumptions.

1. Default browser action will happen before my event listener gets hit.
2. I can dispatch the event again afterward.

```html
<html>
  <input id="file-input" type="file">
</html>

...

<script>
  let ignoreEventForSecondTime = false
  document.getElementById("file-input").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (!ignoreEventForSecondTime) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation() // Don't actually upload yet
      const input = event.target
      validate(input.files) // I only want this to run after users have picked the files
      ignoreEventTheSecondTime = true // Don't run this block after I refire the event
      input.dispatchEvent(event) // The intention is to let whatever event listener handle uploading the files afterwards.
    } else {
      ignoreEventTheSecondTime = false
    }
    
  }, { capturing: true })
</script>
```

Comment: put it in a tmp folder on server, validate there and then send back feedback to front end/ move to real directory only if passes

Comment: @tgkprog I don't have access to any specific servers, this needs to be a piece of frontend code that validates files before some event listener uploads it to a server.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-type-validation-while-uploading-it-using-javascript/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: besides length, mimetype and name nothing else is given out, so might have to read the API and talk to your clients/ manager about next steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have worked. The problem was I couldn't just dispatch the same event I stopped propagation from, as well as changing from 'click' handler to 'change' handler so i can view files after the file dialog have completed.

```html
<html>
  <input id="file-input" type="file">
</html>

...

<script>
  let ignoreEventForSecondTime = false
  document.getElementById("file-input").addEventListener("change", (event) => { // LINE CHANGED
    if (!ignoreEventForSecondTime) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation() // Don't actually upload yet
      const input = event.target
      validate(input.files)
      ignoreEventTheSecondTime = true // Don't run this block after I refire the event
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', event)) // LINE CHANGED
    } else {
      ignoreEventTheSecondTime = false
    }
    
  }, { capturing: true })
</script>
```